# Flutter is not able to find ADB despite being in path

Tags: android, flutter, dart

I'm having an issue where flutter is unable to run anything because it is unable to find ADB. However, I have adb installed (along with the rest of the Android SDK) and it is in my PATH variable. Please advise.

Flutter doctor:

```
    Doctor summary (to see all details, run flutter doctor -v):
[✓] Flutter (Channel stable, 1.22.5, on macOS 11.1 20C69 darwin-x64, locale en-US)
[✓] Android toolchain - develop for Android devices (Android SDK version 30.0.3)
[✓] Xcode - develop for iOS and macOS (Xcode 12.3)
[!] Android Studio (not installed)
[✓] IntelliJ IDEA Ultimate Edition (version 2020.3.1)
[✓] VS Code (version 1.52.1)
[☠] Connected device (the doctor check crashed)
    ✗ Due to an error, the doctor check did not complete. If the error message below is not helpful, please let us know about this issue at https://github.com/flutter/flutter/issues.
    ✗ Exception: Unable to run "adb", check your Android SDK installation and ANDROID_SDK_ROOT environment variable: /Users/akshat/AndroidSDK/platform-tools/adb
    • #0      throwToolExit (package:flutter_tools/src/base/common.dart:14:3)
      #1      AndroidDevices.pollingGetDevices (package:flutter_tools/src/android/android_device_discovery.dart:71:7)
      <asynchronous suspension>
      #2      PollingDeviceDiscovery._populateDevices (package:flutter_tools/src/device.dart:467:60)
      #3      PollingDeviceDiscovery.devices (package:flutter_tools/src/device.dart:457:12)
      #4      DeviceManager.getAllConnectedDevices (package:flutter_tools/src/device.dart:171:20)
      #5      DeviceValidator.validate (package:flutter_tools/src/doctor.dart:975:55)
      #6      asyncGuard.<anonymous closure> (package:flutter_tools/src/base/async_guard.dart:111:32)
      #7      _rootRun (dart:async/zone.dart:1190:13)
      #8      _CustomZone.run (dart:async/zone.dart:1093:19)
      #9      _runZoned (dart:async/zone.dart:1630:10)
      #10     runZonedGuarded (dart:async/zone.dart:1618:12)
      #11     runZoned (dart:async/zone.dart:1547:12)
      #12     asyncGuard (package:flutter_tools/src/base/async_guard.dart:109:3)
      #13     Doctor.startValidatorTasks (package:flutter_tools/src/doctor.dart:191:9)
      #14     Doctor.diagnose (package:flutter_tools/src/doctor.dart:290:47)
      #15     DoctorCommand.runCommand (package:flutter_tools/src/commands/doctor.dart:59:47)
      #16     FlutterCommand.verifyThenRunCommand (package:flutter_tools/src/runner/flutter_command.dart:977:18)
      #17     _rootRunUnary (dart:async/zone.dart:1198:47)
      #18     _CustomZone.runUnary (dart:async/zone.dart:1100:19)
      #19     _FutureListener.handleValue (dart:async/future_impl.dart:143:18)
      #20     Future._propagateToListeners.handleValueCallback (dart:async/future_impl.dart:696:45)
      #21     Future._propagateToListeners (dart:async/future_impl.dart:725:32)
      #22     Future._completeWithValue (dart:async/future_impl.dart:529:5)
      #23     Future._asyncCompleteWithValue.<anonymous closure> (dart:async/future_impl.dart:567:7)
      #24     _rootRun (dart:async/zone.dart:1190:13)
      #25     _CustomZone.run (dart:async/zone.dart:1093:19)
      #26     _CustomZone.runGuarded (dart:async/zone.dart:997:7)
      #27     _CustomZone.bindCallbackGuarded.<anonymous closure> (dart:async/zone.dart:1037:23)
      #28     _microtaskLoop (dart:async/schedule_microtask.dart:41:21)
      #29     _startMicrotaskLoop (dart:async/schedule_microtask.dart:50:5)
      #30     _runPendingImmediateCallback (dart:isolate-patch/isolate_patch.dart:118:13)
      #31     _RawReceivePortImpl._handleMessage (dart:isolate-patch/isolate_patch.dart:169:5)
! Doctor found issues in 2 categories.
```

Snippet of .zshrc containing android environment variables:

```sh
export PATH="${PATH}:/Users/akshat/flutter/bin/"
export ANDROID_SDK_ROOT="${ANDROID_SDK_ROOT}:/Users/akshat/AndroidSDK"
export ANDROID_HOME="/Users/akshat/AndroidSDK"
export PATH="${PATH}:$ANDROID_SDK_ROOT/platform-tools:$ANDROID_HOME/tools"
```

Output of adb --version

```
Android Debug Bridge version 1.0.41
Version 30.0.5-6877874
Installed as /Users/akshat/AndroidSDK/platform-tools/adb
```

Comment: if it cannot find `adb` it means that `/Users/akshat/AndroidSDK/platform-tools` is not in your `PATH`

Comment: It is in my path, evident by being able to run `adb --version` and the output of `which adb`: `/Users/akshat/AndroidSDK/platform-tools/adb`

Comment: ok then, tried `flutter doctor -v`? what does it say?

Comment: Please check updated flutter doctor in the post

Answer (score 0):

Disabling anti-virus fixed it for me